# xamarin live player project should be less than 4194304 bytes but your project size is 6876386 bytes

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am using Xamarin live player for running Android project, but when I run project using Live Player on Visual Studio 2017 Preview 15.3 it shows

> Xamarin live player project should be less than 4194304 bytes but your
>   project size is 6876386 bytes

Here which size is meant? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot find a source to back it up right now, the Xamarin Live Player has a size limit for apps that it can test. Right now the limit is 4 mb, this should probably increase in the future.

Comment: How can I know my project's size?

Comment: Well, it actually is in the error message; your app seems to be around 6mb. But I'm not sure how to check it on before hand

Comment: I meant, is there any way to find any project's size in visual studio and optimize it?